# MS SSMS: How do I quickly clear the criteria pane

Tags: ssms

My job involves a lot of time editing tables in SSMS v18.4

I use the criteria pane a lot as I'll have to query tables then often edit the results. It's much faster than writing SQL (to see the pane I mean: select any table, right click and select "Edit Top 200 rows" then press Ctrl+2).

A simple thing that slows me down a lot is clearing the criteria afterwards for the next job. Is there a quick way of doing this - like a shortcut to clear any criteria entered?

I'd be much more productive if this didn't have to be done by manually! Sounds silly but often my criteria involve a lot of columns and multiple ORs. Please let me know if this question is unclear, would be happy to explain further.

Many thanks,

Laurence

Comment: Using SQL to update your tables is, by far, the better choice. Just get into the habit of using it, and you'll find it's way quicker.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for the quick reply! TBH I'm a bit scared of using SQL. Not been doing the job long, learning on it, and these are HUGE tables. Happy to select, but update or even worse delete I'd rather save until I've got a bit more comfortable with the role. Worst case using the criteria pane is I make a mess of one record. Worse case with SQL is no more table lol

Comment: You're scared of using `UPDATE` but not using the "edit top 200 rows" feature, which is literally what that does? :) If you're ever concerned about what a DML statement will do, then `SELECT` it first, then comment out the `SELECT` part, and complete the DML statement. Then you explicitly know what rows are being updated.

Comment: @Larnu that makes sense. Great tip thank you! I will try that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "Show SQL Pane" and just delete "WHERE" part completely.
Alternatively you can close and re-open the window.

Comment: Just tried deleting WHERE. It works great, really cool (I think - undocumented) feature. Thank you so much! Never really used the SQL pane before, this will be a great learning tool in general.